# Java Swing Wait

Tags: java, swing, wait

I am making a java code and I need to wait a few milliseconds.

```
while(true)
{
    //wait
    //more code
}
```

How can I make my code wait? I usually code in C# and i can do `Thread.Sleep()` but I didn’t found a way to make it work in java. Also, this is my current full code if you are wondering:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main{
    public static void main(String [] arg){
        Boolean isEnded = false;
        Scanner newScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Weird 3N+1 Calculator");
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("No Seed Entered.");
        
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        jf.setSize(300,300);
        jf.getContentPane().add(jl);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Enter a seed: ");
        String seed = newScan.nextLine();
        Integer x = Integer.valueOf(seed);
        
        while(isEnded == false)         
        {
            //Thread.sleep(100);
            
            if(x == 1)  
            {
                isEnded = true;
                jl.setText("Last Number Is: " + x);
            }       
            else
            {
                if(x % 2 == 0)  
                {       
                    System.out.println(x / 2);
                    x = x / 2;
                    jl.setText("Now:" + x);
                }   
                else
                {   
                    System.out.println(x * 3 + 1);  
                    x = x * 3 + 1;
                    jl.setText("Now:" + x);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I just started coding in Java. My code is probably not well made and could be improved. Thanks

-Me

Comment: What is the purpose of waiting do you think?

Comment: I want it to wait so we can see the numbers changing and not just seeing directly the result that is anyway always be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to wait here is `Thread.sleep(n)` method. In the situation, where you have multiple threads, you can tell `threadA` to wait `treadB` finished by calling `treadB.join()` method.

Comment: Well, I don’t know what these ```threadA```, ```threadB``` or ```threadB.join()```. Also, is ```n``` a variable? Thanks for answering that fast by the way.

Comment: Yes, by `n` I mean number of milliseconds. About `threadA/B` I mean multithreading which is unused in your solution.

Comment: Ohh ok so ```n``` would be 100 or something like. Also, do I just put the thread.join() thing and it will multithread? I’ve never done that before.

Comment: No, you can read more about multithreading here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm